# Sorting just two elements using STL

Tags: c++, stl

Quite often I have two variables `foo1` and `foo2` which are numeric types. They represent the *bounds* of something.

A user supplies values for them, but like a recalcitrant musician, not necessarily in the correct order!

So my code is littered with code like

```
if (foo2 < foo1){
    std::swap(foo2, foo1);
}
```

Of course, this is an idiomatic sort with two elements not necessarily contiguous in memory. Which makes me wonder: is there a STL one-liner for this?

Comment: Minus one? In what way can I improve this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but when you notice you wrote the same code twice it's time to write a function for it:

```
template<typename T, typename P = std::less<T>>
void swap_if(T& a, T& b, P p = P()) {
    if (p(a, b)) {
        using std::swap;
        swap(a, b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends though, one can easily put the original example on one line `if(foo1<foo2) std::swap(foo1,foo2);` and the reader will instantly know what the code is doing. If I saw `sort2` I could guess what it does but I'd have to check the definition (perhaps it's just the 2nd version of a function which sorts stl containers?)

Comment: How about a third argument, `typename P = std::less<T>` and `P p = P()`?

Comment: @KerrekSB that's nice!

Comment: Never write duplicate code, unless doing so yields more readable code and there is nothing to be gained by deduplicating it. In this case it just seems pointless.

Comment: @jalf: Actually this code is subtle. It took Stepanov fifteen years to get `min` and `max` right. This function in isolation doesn't quite show the subtlety, but the point is that you want `min`, `max` and `sort` to be compatible with respect to stability of equivalent elements, and that's easy to mess up if you hand-roll code yourself in random places.

Comment: I don't like this because `swap_if` doesn't actually tell what the function does; I'd have to look up the function definition to see what a line like `swap_if(x, y);` does.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: Agreed, a name like `sort_2` or so would be more explanatory.

Comment: Reminds me of this gag: "IDEs make doing the wrong thing easier". Here, we see the programmer automating the wrong thing. At the cost of fragmenting the domain with many levels of "accidental" abstraction. You want to avoid this. See Raabe's answer.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to take a step back and let the type system do the job for you: introduce a type like `Bounds` (or `Interval`) which takes care of the issue. Something like

```
template <typename T>
class Interval {
public:
  Interval( T start, T end ) : m_start( start ), m_end( end ) {
    if ( m_start > m_end ) {
      std::swap( m_start, m_end );
    }
  }

  const T &start() const { return m_start; }
  const T &end() const { return m_end; }

private:
  T m_start, m_end;
};
```

This not only centralizes the swap-to-sort code, it also helps asserting the correct order very early on so that you don't pass around two elements all the time, which means that you don't even need to check the order so often in the first place.

An alternative approach to avoid the issue is to express the boundaries as a pair of 'start value' and 'length' where the 'length' is an unsigned value.

Comment: OP specified they are not necessarily contiguous in memory.

Comment: @райтфолд The take-away is to not pass around two elements in the first place but introduce a dedicated type which enforces the assertion; this is totally independant of how the values are stored.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::minmax`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax) returns pair of smallest and largest element. Which you can use with `std::tie`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 7;
    int b = 5;
    std::tie(a, b) = std::minmax({a,b});
    std::cout << a << " " << b; // output: 5 7
}
```

Note that this isn't the same as the `if(a < b) std::swap(a,b);` version. For example this doesn't work with move-only elements.

Comment: Does that [actually work](http://ideone.com/eQSKy4)?! (You cheated by changing the problem!)

Comment: @KerrekSB Did I? It solves the problem the OP has. (that's true it doesn't have the same semantics - the question involved numeric types) Now, the question why it doesn't work with two elements instead of initializer list is interesting, and I'll probably ask it soon.

Comment: I assume it doesn't work because the two element version returns a pair of __references__ not values.

Answer (score -4):

if the data type of your value that you're going to compare is not already in c++. You need to overload the comparison operators.

For example, if you want to compare foo1 and foo2

```
template <class T>
class Foo { 
  private: 
    int value;     // value 

  public: 
    int GetValue() const {
        return value;
    }
}; 

bool operator<(const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs) {
    return (lhs.GetValue() < rhs.GetValue());
}
```

If your value is some type of int, or double. Then you can use the std::list<>::sort member function.

For example:

```
std::list<int> integer_list;
int_list.push_back(1);
int_list.push_back(8);
int_list.push_back(9);
int_list.push_back(7);
int_list.sort();

for(std::list<int>::iterator list_iter = int_list.begin(); list_iter != int_list.end(); list_iter++)
{
    std::cout<<*list_iter<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `std::set`? It has the invariant that it's sorted.

Comment: The question didn't ask how to write `operator<` or sort a `std::list`